# Design using 5x1 Mux, would this have any complications?

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer, 7segmentdisplay, state-machines

I am building a stopwatch with 5 counters. All are BCD counters with the exception of 1 modulo-6 counter (10ths, 1s, 10s, 1mins, 10mis.)

I intend to pass these to the 7 segment displays on my board. To do this I plan to serialize the 7 segment display's since I know that all of the displays share a common cathode. To do this I wired the count values to a 5x1 bus mux with 3 select lines which are sourced from the state value of a FSM (S0,S1,S2,S3,S4) or (000,001,010,011,100.) The state values are then placed through a 3-5 decoder to activate the enable of 5 displays.

I did the 5x1 to be more concise in my code, when I do begin coding. I know a 5x1 mux is not as common compared to a 8x1 mux, but I just want to know if this might potentially cause some errors in functionality. Should I just tie the other 3 values of an 8x1 mux to 0000, and should I make the FSM have a total of 8 states? Am I going on the correct path as it is?

[image: Here is the design schematic for visual reference]

Comment: Please show a schematic of the proposed design instead of describing it with words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 'illegal' states should not happen, but perhaps because of a bad reset or other glitch may occur. You should take care that the FSM exits these states in a useful way.

Since this would only affect the display temporarily, It is probably sufficient to ensure that any of these states exits to one of the 'good' states. One way would be {S5,S6,S7,S0} -> S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> S4 -> S5 -> S0.

Depending on how you want to handle the display during an error, you could just blank it (no segments) if S5,S6,S7 is detected, or you could display an error (e.g. '-' symbol ?).